# cómo puedo colocar el logo del lado derecho y el navbar del lado izquierdo?

Tags: html, css

Tengo rato tratando de hacer esto para dejar mi cabecera lista y no he podido...

¿Cómo puedo colocar el logo del lado derecho y el *navbar* del lado izquierdo, respetando exactamente el aspecto visual?

Es decir, invertir las posiciones en que se encuentran cada uno... por favor si me pueden ayudar... aquí coloco el código  a ver si lo miran en el navegador y captan la idea... gracias de antemano, de verdad lo agradecería

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>bootstrap 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->

    <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-lg-0 "> 

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 

            <!-- Add logo -->
            <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png"
            width="90" height="80" alt=""> 
        </a> 

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse" 
                data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 

                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
        </button> 

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="navbarResponsive"> 
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> 
                <li class="nav-item active"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home 
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a> 
                </li> 
                <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a> 
                </li> 
                <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a> 
                </li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </nav> 




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, rodea con un div tu logo, el botón de colapso y los enlaces de tu nav.
A dicho div ponle las siguientes clases de css **"d-flex justify-content-between flex-row-reverse align-items-center flex-wrap"**, estas clases hacen que el display sea "flex" y puedes separar los elementos a los extremos, también te permite invertir los elementos.
Por último, elimina la clase "ml-auto" del tag "ul" ya que esta clase aplica un "margin-left" sobrante del ancho del padre.
Ejecuta el siguiente html y deberías de obtener el resultado que quieres, saludos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>bootstrap 4</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAVIGATION -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-lg-0">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-row-reverse align-items-center flex-wrap" style="width: 100%">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <!-- Add logo -->
        <img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20190710102234/download3.png" width="90" height="80" alt="" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```